# How do I monitor changes to a specific field in Firebase database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, onchange

I have a database stored in Firebase and wanted to use the 'functions' to check whether a record in the database was > n days old. I understand the
    onChange()
function in JavaScript could achieve this for me. Thank you!

Comment: you can do it with snapshotchanges inside payload, call a valuechanges in a certain field of document

Answer (score 0):

In my project, we often use this pattern. Use onChange() to detect changes, and then a helper function to check if the change happened to a specific field. This helper function is for example called `checkIfChangedHappenedToAtLeastOneOfProvidedPaths`, and you can use it by providing the path to check, for example: `checkIfChangedHappenedToAtLeastOneOfProvidedPaths(change.before.data(), change.after.data(), ['daysOld'])`

`checkIfChangedHappenedToAtLeastOneOfProvidedPaths` uses 2 helper functions to achieve this (`difference` & `getDifferenceCombine`). Let me know what you think, here is the code (in typescript):

**checkIfChangedHappenedToAtLeastOneOfProvidedPaths**

```
/**
 * The purpose of this function is to analyze the change between two objects.
 * If a change happened to the prvoided path(s), return true, otherwise false,
 * Usecase: Use this function if you only care about change at a certain path.
 * Example: Run only update function if change happened to "stripe" object, at groups
 * @export
 * @param {*} oldObject
 * @param {*} newObject
 * @param {string[]} pathsToCheck
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
export function checkIfChangedHappenedToAtLeastOneOfProvidedPaths(oldObject: object, newObject: object, pathsToCheck: string[]): boolean {
    const combinedChanges = getDifferenceCombine(oldObject, newObject);
    const flatObject = flat(combinedChanges);
    let changeHappened = false;
    pathsToCheck.forEach((path) => {
        const inFlatObject = flatObject[path] != null;
        const inCombinedObject = get(combinedChanges, path, null) != null;
        if (inFlatObject || inCombinedObject) {
            changeHappened = true;
        }
    });
    return changeHappened;
}
```

**Helper functions**

```
export function difference(object: any, base: any): any {
    return transform(object, (result, value, key) => {
        if (base == null || object == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (!isEqual(value, base[key])) {
            result[key] = isObject(value) && isObject(base[key]) ? difference(value, base[key]) : value;
        }
    });
}

export function getDifferenceCombine(oldObject: object, newObject: object): object {
    const diffObject = difference(newObject, oldObject);
    const diffObject2 = difference(oldObject, newObject);
    return {...diffObject, ...diffObject2};
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since everything updates in real time, you can query this specific field if you want to monitor it. For example, lets say you have a child node "createdAt" with a value of a Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP.

```
var n = 1452508000000; //random timestamp in milliseconds, 
//since this is how firebase saves a server value timestamp or 
//this can be Date.now() if you convert your createdAt value 
//to whatever date format you prefer.

var ref = firebase.database().ref('path/to/your/data');
ref.orderByChild("createdAt").startAt(n).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key);
  //will list all keys that were created on or after the timestamp value
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#startAt